# Getting only the data from a select statement in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I am getting some data from a database, and it returns an array `$rows` as shown below:

[image]

However the returned rows doesn't contain a pure array with the CV data. I would like just to have a pure array which has only the values.

My code:

```
$sql =  'SELECT CATEGORY_VALUE from '.self::TABLE_NAME. ' where E_ID = :E_ID and C_TYPE = :C_TYPE';
        $where = array('E_ID'=>$id, 'C_TYPE'=> $c);
        $stmt =  $this->_db->query($sql,$where);
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $rows;
```

Comment: Use `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN`.

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstanding of how php arrays work.  You can learn more here.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

In PHP, you would get the value you want by doing the following:
$rows[0]['CATEGORY_VALUE'] will return 'H3

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I know that I can use $rows[0]['CATEGORY_VALUE'] to get the value. However, I just need to get all the values of all the rows in one array so that I can get the first value by using only $rows[0]